# Async call on aura:method?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, asynchronous

I got an aura:method inside my child component that returns an async response

```
<!-- inside child component -->
<aura:method name="saveMethod" action="{!c.saveChanges}" access="public" />
```

```
<!-- inside parent -->
<c:accounts aura:id="accountData />
```

```
// parent controller
let accountComp = component.find("accountData")
accountComp.saveMethod
// how to wait until this saveMethod is finished before I continue?
```

Should I chain another callback inside the parent? The `saveMyChanges` itself inside the child component is already a callback

````
// saveChanges function inside child
let action = component.get("c.saveAccountData");
action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
    //sucess message
    if (response.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
        // server code
    }
})
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Two options exist in Aura.

## Promise

```
childMethod: function (component, params) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let action = component.get("c.action");
    action.setParams(params);
    action.setCallback(this, (response) => {
      if (response.getState() == 'COMPLETE') {
        resolve(response.getReturnValue());
      }
      if (response.getState() == 'ERROR') {
        reject(response.getError());
      }
    });
  })
}
```

Note that this is a helper method; `component` and `params` should come from the controller method:

```
childMethod: function (component, event, helper) {
  return helper.childMethod(component, event.getParam('arguments'));
}
```

The parent calls the method as:

```
childComponent.childMethod(param).then(
  (result) => {
    // Handle result here
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Deal with errors here
  })
);
```

## Callback

The second method is documented in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods_async.htm):

First, provide a Function parameter:

```
<aura:method name="childMethod"
  description="Sample method with server-side call">
    <aura:attribute name="callback" type="Function" />
</aura:method>
```

Then, use that parameter later:

```
if(response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
  callback(response.getReturnValue());
}
```

---

For the documentation, I'll reproduce all the code here in case the link breaks:

```
<!-- c:auraMethod -->
<aura:component controller="SimpleServerSideController">
    <aura:method name="echo"
      description="Sample method with server-side call">
        <aura:attribute name="callback" type="Function" />
    </aura:method>
    
    <p>This component has an aura:method definition.</p>
</aura:component>
```

---

```
/* auraMethodController.js */
({
    echo : function(cmp, event) {
        var params = event.getParam('arguments');
        var callback;
        if (params) {
            callback = params.callback;
        }

        var action = cmp.get("c.serverEcho");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                console.log("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
                // return doesn't work for async server action call
                //return response.getReturnValue();
                // call the callback passed into aura:method
                if (callback) callback(response.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                // do something
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                          errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
})
```

---

```
public with sharing class SimpleServerSideController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String serverEcho() {
        return ('Hello from the server');
    }
}
```

---

```
/* auraMethodCallerController.js */
({    
    callAuraMethodServerTrip : function(component, event, helper) {
        var childCmp = component.find("child");
        // call the aura:method in the child component
        childCmp.echo(function(result) {
            console.log("callback for aura:method was executed");
            console.log("result: " + result);
        });
    },
})
```

---